# Windows Share Permissions for Domain Admins not working

Tags: windows, active-directory, file-permissions, network-share

I'm setting up a new share that I've enabled enumerated access on. I'm looking to limit people access to files on a certain folder. I've setup other folders that restrict access unless your in a security group. This folder thats giving me trouble was copied over from another network share. When I create a folder from scratch everything works fine so I'm curious if thats whats giving me issues.

The folder I'm trying to access is
x:/Limerock/Projects/"Project Name"

If I go into the security tab and check my effective access it says that I have full control:
[image]

The user I'm signed into is joe.jankowiak which is part of the Domain Admins security group. Domain Admins owns all the folders in above this and has full control.

[image]

When trying to enter the folder it tells me I need to request permission. I'm an admin so it goes through and adds "joe.jankowiak" to the full control list in the security permissions.

[image]

Why is it not taking my domain admin credentials to enter this folder? I'm seeing other weird behavior such as it saying "Unable to display current owner." and "You must have read permissions to view the properties of this object". Clicking continue lets me see it.

[image]

Everything looks right, I've setup 6 other new folders in the exact same manner and they work fine. I've signed in and out many times but it hasn't fixed it. Weird enough, another computer I signed into lets me access the folder just fine. Is there a way to reload file permissions since logging in/out doesn't seem to do it. Is there a command like gpupdate that I should run?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before andyou might need to do the following operations in order:

-Replace Ownership on the folder and replace all child object ownership too=>apply or OK

-Close the security properties and re-open it again

-Add Domain Admins as full control and Replace all child object permissions... =>apply/OK

That should do it

Comment: Hmm, I tried it in that order and I still have the same issue. I should mention this only is an issue when Remote Desktop'd into my server as my domain account. On my domain computer I can create a top level directory in the share, set the only permission as "Domain Admins | Full access" and it works fine. Doing that in remote desktop exactly the same, it tells me I don't have access and adds my domain account to the permission list. I guess I'll just stop trying to edit these things from remote desktop.

Comment: Its just confusing because if I add another group that I'm apart of to the folder it works perfectly. I'm just trying to ensure domain admins have access to all folders, even if they arn't in a particular group.